utilzzar droidcam com pipewire en endeavourOS
He instalado droidcam en mi dristibución liux endeavourOS pero no he podido que mi celular pueda captar lo que hablo, he seguido lo que dice la documentación pero no me ha funcionado, y esto e slo que dice: Con Pipewire, abra pavucontrol, pestaña Configuración.  Probablemente existan varios dispositivos llamados “Audio incorporado”, uno de ellos es droidcam.  Elija el perfil Pro Audio, vaya a la pestaña Dispositivos de entrada y verifique qué medidor reacciona a la entrada de audio del teléfono (por ejemplo, Audio integrado Pro 1), este es el dispositivo de entrada de audio deseado.
Dentro de pavucontrol ahora puede configurar este dispositivo como entrada predeterminada o elegirlo como dispositivo de entrada para aplicaciones individuales, etc. Alguien que haya solucionado algo asi.
